# Context switch of critical section

Tags: operating-system, synchronization, mutex, critical-section

If process that acquired a mutex lock over a critical section gets context switched during its execution in critical section for some other process, doesn't that create possible issues if that new process also manipulates some global data structure used in previous critical section?

Comment: Yes, of course.  A mutex only works if all threads that require access acquire the mutex first.

Comment: I guess i was thinking of two different processes where they have different code yet they still manipulate same global data structure, perhaps a kernel one.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a danger, because that other thread, although it may have another code, may still be able to ACCESS the shared resource, remember that shared resource is GLOBAL.